# Getting inside of an APK

Tags: applications, apk

Is there any way to interrogate another app's internal parameters?

Long story short; a backgammon app is using cheating dice, if I can grab the RNG seed it's using (and then manipulating) I can test it against the latest version of the software that publishes the seed (and has an improved game engine......they only released the new functionality once they'd sorted out the AI).

Comment: Programs that analyze APK files in detail are available for PC/Macs like Jadx-Gui or apktool. And there are a lot if commercial programs can do so. Note that questions on app recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: I was referring to run time programs, sorry if I didn't make that clear.  The developer has hidden his "let's choose 2 dice" algorithm behind ProGuard.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "run time programs". If the app is obfuscated you have to use your brain to find what you are looking for. Proguard renames and potentially moves classes and methods, so nothing too complicated. Jadx-Gui has some deobfuscation functions included, but it can only improve the situation, the original names are gone. Android itself doesn't care for difficult to read names, it just executes the code as it is.

Comment: So I run the analysing software - I then run the backgammon app.  The analysing software reports back various metrics from the backgammon app.  I'm sorry if I've made that overly confusing for you.  Years ago on a ZX Spectrum I could load a disassembler into memory, load the target program and the disassembler would display the various parameters being used by the target program.  That was 45 years ago, please tell me we haven't regressed to the point that unscrupulous programmers can get away with blue murder undetected these days?

Comment: Static program analysis still works. You just have to consider that there are about a dozen or more frameworks that can be used to build Android apps based in various languages resulting in different code. Then in each language there are multiple ways to get something random. Therefore if you are searching for a randomness function you have round about 100 different ways an app could have implement it. The haystack is ready for you, the needle is already waiting...